# How to get 2 divs under each other?

Tags: html, css

Like this:

[image]

---

*Note:* That's a table,and the table gets "not responsive" on phones, as it doesn't fix, you need to scroll sideways on phones. Hard to explain.

This is the code: (without tables)

Real question: How do you get it like the one with tables, just.. without table?

```css
.avatar {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px
}

.navn {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 184px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #14967c
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/Ullix21" target="_blank">
    <img style="float: left;" src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/33/33be922a4e16b1bbb7872ab2a149ca1920276571_full.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/16BitBacon" target="_blank">
    <img style="float: left;" src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/83/83ec24eb38514fe4ed57360d4b656089dba0e280_full.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="navn" style="display: inline-block; float:left; vertical-align: top;">Ullix</div>
<div class="navn" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">Wombo</div>
```

Comment: Isn't your code the same as the pic you post ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be good if you wrap both avatar and navn in a container?

Comment: I dont see any tables in the Snippet.

Comment: You could just `float:left` to float both divs. Not sure what you mean  by tables?

Comment: You already have a kinda table layout in your result? But if you want to go fancy, use `flex`.

Comment: No you can't @zik

Comment: @Simon not really sure I understand your question correctly, in that case?

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

Put the `.navm` inside the `.avatar`. In my code I removed the class of `.navm` and use `.avatar>div` in my CSS instead.

The name is displayed underneath the image, but is in the same div. So when adjusting screen size, they always stay under each other.

```css
.avatar {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px
}
.avatar img {
  display: block; /* removes white space */
}
.avatar>div {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #14967c
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/Ullix21" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/33/33be922a4e16b1bbb7872ab2a149ca1920276571_full.jpg"></a>
  <div>Ullix</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/16BitBacon" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/83/83ec24eb38514fe4ed57360d4b656089dba0e280_full.jpg"></a>
  <div>Wombo</div>
</div>
```

You probably need to add some media queries for mobile views...

Answer (score 0):

```
I think, this is how I understood your question, correct me if I am wrong:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web page</title>
    <style>
    .avatar {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    }
    .avatar img {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 178px;
}

    div .desc {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #14967c;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="avatar">
  <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/Ullix21" target="_blank">
    <img style="float: left;" src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/33/33be922a4e16b1bbb7872ab2a149ca1920276571_full.jpg"></a>
    <div class="desc"><strong>Ullix</strong></div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/16BitBacon" target="_blank">
    <img style="float: left;" src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/83/83ec24eb38514fe4ed57360d4b656089dba0e280_full.jpg"></a>
    <div class="desc"><strong>Wombo</strong></div>
</div>
<!--
<div class="navn" style="display: inline-block; float:left; vertical-align: top;">Ullix</div>
<div class="navn" style="display: inline-block; flaot:left; vertical-align: top;">Wombo</div>
-->
  </body>
</html>
```

To make it more responsive, Just add media queries, check below link:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use css flexbox

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```